# TypeError object takes no parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I'm simply trying to make a code how to use `super` and `__new__`. Here's the code:

```
class Person(object):
    def __new__(cls, name, age):
        print('__new__called')
        return super(Person, cls).__new__(cls, name, age)
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        print('__init__called')
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    def __str__(self):
        return('<Person:%s(%s)>'%(self.name, self.age))
if __name__ == '__main__':  
    piglei = Person("piglei", 24)
    print(piglei)
```

Python raises a `TypeError` and says something about line 4, `object() takes no parameters`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`object.__new__` doesn't accept any arguments. Your `super` call in `__new__` will fail:

```
return super(Person, cls).__new__(cls, name, age)
```

since you also pass `name` and `age` up to `object.__new__`.

You don't need to pass these up to `object`; either drop the `__new__` definition all together or, don't pass any of the arguments to it:

```
return super(Person, cls).__new__(cls)
```

Either way, there's really no reason to use `__new__` here but I'm guessing you're experimenting. If you are, take note that you can also drop `Person` and `cls` in `super` and use it's zero argument form, i.e:

```
return super().__new__(cls)
```